# Bash Script Loop through MySQL row and use curl and grep

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, curl

I have a mysql database, with a table :
url      |      words

And datas like, for example :

```
------Column URL-------   -------Column Words------

www.firstwebsite.com    |   hello, hi

www.secondwebsite.com   |   someword, someotherword
```

I want to loop through that table to check if the word is present in the content of the website specified by the url.

I have something like this :

```
!/bin/bash

mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD DATABASE --skip-column-names -e "SELECT url, keyword FROM things" | while read url keyword; do
    content=$(curl -sL $url)
    echo $content | egrep -q $keyword
    status=$?

    if test $status -eq 0 ; then
        # Found...
    else
        # Not found...
    fi
done
```

One problems :

It's very slow : how set curl to optimize the load time of each website, don't load images, things like that ?

Also, Is it a good idea to put things like that in a shell script, or is it better to create a php script, and call it with curl ?

Thanks !

Comment: why!? why are you filtering in bash? Why not just `select ... where keyword like '%$keyword%'`?

Comment: I have to get the website content. And then search the keyword in it, how do that with a sql request ?

Comment: For example : I get url=www.somesite.com , and keyword=ok. curl get the content of the website, and then I go check if the keyword is in it.

Comment: Ah right. Totally missed the curl call in there

Comment: Could you add to your question the first couple of lines you get out of your database with `mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD DATABASE -e "SELECT url, keyword FROM things"`?

Comment: Done with some examples ;)

Comment: For the first problem use `--skip-column-names` with `mysql`.

Comment: I edit my first message, now it works, but it is a little slow, how can I optimize this ? For 25 url it takes 30 seconds, any way to speed up this ?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands your script will not work as you might expect when you have multiple keywords per row as in your example. The reason is that when you pass `hello, hi` to `egrep` it will look for the exact string "hello, hi" in its input, *not* for either "hello" or "hi". You can fix this without making changes to what's in your database by turning  each list of keywords into an `egrep`-compatible regular expression with `sed`. You'll also need to remove the `|` from `mysql`'s output, e.g, with `awk`.

`curl` doesn't retrieve images when downloading a webpage's HTML. If the order in which the URLs are queried does not matter to you then you can speed things up by making the whole thing asynchronous with `&`.

```
#!/bin/bash

handle_url() {
    if curl -sL "$1" | egrep -q "$2"; then
        echo 1 # Found...
    else
        echo 0 # Not found...
    fi
}

mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD DATABASE --skip-column-names -e "SELECT url, keyword FROM things" | awk -F \| '{ print $1, $2 }' | while read url keywords; do
    keywords=$(echo $keywords | sed -e 's/, /|/g;s/^/(/;s/$/)/;')
    handle_url "$url" "$keywords" &
done
```